# JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateArticle fails with "null"

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to update a Liferay Web Content, creating a new version, so I wrote this Groovy script:

```
import com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext
import com.liferay.portlet.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil

long companyId=10154
long userId=12328
long groupId=17074933
long folderId = 0
String articleId="17075078"
double version=1
String content='<?xml version="1.0"?><root available-locales="en_US" default-locale="en_US"><static-content language-id="en_US"><![CDATA[Bonjour]]></static-content></root>'

ServiceContext serviceContext = new com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext()
serviceContext.setAddCommunityPermissions(true)
serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true)
serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(groupId)
serviceContext.setCompanyId(companyId)
serviceContext.setUserId(userId)

JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateArticle(
    userId, groupId, folderId, articleId, version, content, serviceContext)
```

Unfortunately, the Groovy script console fails, and `catalina.out` only contains this minimalistic debug information:

```
null
```

The identifiers are the ones I have found in the Liferay web interface. Just to check, I verified the content of MySQL, the values are correct:

```
mysql> select companyId, userId, groupId, folderId, articleId, version from JournalArticle order by createDate desc limit 1;
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
| companyId | userId | groupId  | folderId | articleId | version |
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
|     10154 |  12328 | 17074933 |        0 | 17075078  |       1 |
+-----------+--------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

What I am doing wrong?

I am using Liferay Portal Enterprise Edition 6.2.10 EE GA1. The same code works well on Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA6, so I might need a workaround to achieve what I want.

When I use `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.updateContent` instead it works, but I can't use it as it does not create a new version of the web content (it just replaces the version).

Answer (score 0):

Self instantiation of a ServiceContext can be error-prone, because you don't know which fields the service implementation requires. I guess there is a setter for your ServiceContext missing, so the updateArticle (or somewhere below eg: validate , updateAsset ...) throws a Nullpointer Exception.
Rather use:

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(JournalArticle.class.getName(), actionRequest);
```

Otherwise, you might need to debug (if possible) the Service-Implementation while executing your script.